# Error assigning string to object

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search for a file, in d:\ folder with the name Division_Application_Partner.xlsx where Division Application and Partner are variables holding string values.

This is the code I gave:

```
Set WorkbookPath = Dir(path & Division + "_" + Application + "_" + TradingPartner + ".xlsx")`enter code here`
```

It throws an error saying " Compile Error: Type Mismtach "

Is the name of the file im giving wrong

Here's the code:

```
Dim WorkbookPath As WorkBook
Dim path as String
Division = Range("C11").Value
Application = Range("C15").Value
TradingPartner = Range("C19").Value
path = "d:\"

'MsgBox (path)
'MsgBox (Division)
'MsgBox (Application)
MsgBox (TradingPartner)


  If Len(Dir(path & Division & "_" & Application & "_" & TradingPartner & ".xlsx")) = 0 Then

  Set  WorkbookPath = Division & "_" & Application & "_" & TradingPartner & ".xlsx"



  End If
```

I tried concatenating using & like you suggested. Still it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try assign string to object, this why you getting an error

> Dim WorkbookPath As WorkBook

Better try

```
Dim myWkb as Workbook 
Set myWkb = Workbooks.Open(your_concat_string)
```

and dont use reserved words

> Application

Finally

```
Sub test()
Dim wkbExternWorkbook As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim strDivision As String, strApplication As String, strTradingPartner As String

strDivision = Range("C11").Value
strApplication = Range("C15").Value
strTradingPartner = Range("C19").Value
strPath = "D:\"

If Len(Dir(strPath & strDivision & "_" & strApplication & "_" & strTradingPartner & ".xlsx")) <> 0 Then
    Set wkbExternWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strDivision & "_" & strApplication & "_" & strTradingPartner & ".xlsx")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it shows that the file might have got renamed or removed. I had a copy of "your_concat_string" file renamed in the format thats required. in a different location in D:\ . Is there anything we can do about this ?

Comment: I mean your concat string that are `path & division & "_" & application & "_" & tradingpartner &   ".xlsx"`, so finaly your line will be:
`Set myWkb = Workbooks.Open(path & division & "_" & application & "_" & tradingpartner &   ".xlsx")`
sorry for my english =)

Answer (score 0):

I would start with using `&` exclusively for string concatenation. The use of `+` is primarily for adding numbers though it *can* concatenate strings. However, there are all sorts of caveats to that when using `option strict` and so forth, so you're better off using what was intended.

The other thing you should do is actually output all those variables before attempting to concatenate or pass them to `Dir`. Something like:

```
MsgBox "[" & path & "]"
```

repeated for all the others as well. The output of that may well point to the problem.

Comment: Its still showing that error even before it goes to the MsgBox line. When I start executing that macro, line by line, I have the MsgBox() command for the variables as suggested before, first, followed by the DIr function line.

Comment: @SUNDARRAM, if you've put the MsgBox before the line you state is erroring, and you're still getting an error before the message box appears, I'll bet money that the error is not on the line you're given. Show the whole macro _with_ the msgbox in it.

Comment: MsgBox (path)
MsgBox (Division)
MsgBox (Application)
MsgBox (TradingPartner)

WorkbookPath = Dir(path & Division & "_" & Application & "_" & TradingPartner & ".xlsx")

Comment: @SUNDARRAM, post the entire code somewhere (like pastebin) and give us a link, we'll move it into your question. Unless you can edit it into your own question, I'm not sure how much rep you need for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim application As Variant
Dim division As Variant
Dim WorkbookPath As String
Dim tradingpartner As Variant
Dim path As String
division = Range("C11").Value
application = Range("C15").Value
tradingpartner = Range("C19").Value
path = "d:\"

'MsgBox (path)
'MsgBox (Division)
'MsgBox (Application)
MsgBox (tradingpartner)

If Len(Dir(path & division & "_" & application & "_" & tradingpartner &   ".xlsx")) = 0 Then
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs division & "_" & application & "_" & tradingpartner & ".xlsx"
End If
End Sub
```

You would first add the workbook and then save it using the created name.

Comment: its not working. It goes into the If loop, but when checked, the length shouldn't be 0, cos it just came out of the loop going to the next step.

Comment: You need to add the path information to the saveas statement:
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & division & "_" & application & "_" & tradingpartner & ".xlsx"

Tested on my machine. If the file exists, it will skip the IF statement.